# How to specify integer response variable in rpart R

Tags: r, model, predict, rpart

I have an issue rpart function. I have a set of integer response variables from 0 to 100 and many explanatory numeric variables. How can I make sure that the predict of the rpart tree will result in integer values? Using classification model is not an option as that many different 'levels' of Y take forever to compute.

Do you know any tricks?

Comment: Why not just `round` the predictions?

Comment: This seems to be a data modeling question and not really a programming question. You're likely to get better answers at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] rather than Stack Overflow.